# Is it possible to use workmanger instead of ScheduledExecutorService for showing interstitial ad in evey n minutes?

Tags: android, admob, android-workmanager

I want show my interstitial ad in every 10 minutes and most tutorials suggests using ScheduledExecutorService but I wonder if I can use workmanager instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. WorkManager is specifically meant for deferrable, persistent work and not for work 1) tied to your UI or 2) on a specific timing schedule. From the [WorkManager Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager):

> The WorkManager API makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or device restarts.
>
> WorkManager is not intended for in-process background work that can safely be terminated if the app process goes away or for tasks that require immediate execution. Please review the [background processing guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) to see which solution meets your needs.